# How to find users in a particular tablespace in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, tablespace

I have created a new tablespace and also some users. I have assigned those users to the tablespace. What is the query for finding out the users for the tablespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME,USERNAME 
 FROM  DBA_TS_QUOTAS 
 WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = '<your_tablespace>';
```

If Tablespace quotas are not available, then:

```
select USERNAME, DEFAULT_TABLESPACE, TEMPORARY_TABLESPACE
from DBA_USERS
where DEFAULT_TABLESPACE='<your_tablespace>';
```

Comment: You are welcome.Please do mark the answer as useful.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Abhijit. Could u also mark it as the best answer since there are no other answers so far?..:)

Comment: How? I am new in here.

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem.This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".